# how to flip image using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 10-15 images which are coming from server as  per request, i want to use flip image effect for those images using Jquery.
Any suggestion and code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/css-fliphttp://davidwalsh.name/css-flip it will be helpful to you..

Comment: I don't get the closing here. It looks really random... OP **didn't** ask for a book, tool, library, or any off-site resource.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to define a CSS class :

```
img.flipped {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

and then apply this class using jQuery :

```
$(myImageElement).addClass('flipped');
```

Read more : [Using CSS transform on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms)

Note that this wouldn't work on IE8. And I don't see any client-side solution for this browser (given that canvas isn't available either).